# Device's default layout direction changes application's default layout direction when device language is changed

Tags: android, orientation, direction

Recently i received reports from users about application layout direction disrupted and isn't displayed correct.

I made all direction **ltr** in the `style.xml` but some users change **phone language**.as a result, Device default layout direction changes and cause application direction reverse.(but i don't want)

**ltr** changes to **rtl**

**rtl** changes to **ltr**

my assumptions were that if i set static layout direction in `style.xml` layout never changes its direction but it didn't work and direction is changed.what i have to do?how can i prevent layout direction change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can force LTR in your activities.

```
<item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
```

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
</style>
```

You can also use it in layouts directly and combine different directions on a single view.

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

For example:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_linearlayout_rtl"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_linearlayout_rtl_child_1"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layoutDirection="ltr" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_linearlayout_rtl_child_2"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layoutDirection="rtl" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_linearlayout_rtl_child_3"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layoutDirection="inherit" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_linearlayout_rtl_child_4"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layoutDirection="locale" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It can be used since API 17.

Hope it helps

Comment: Good I will test it soon 

Comment: this worked <item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Set this in manifest.xml inside `<application>` Tag

Comment: android:supportsRtl is by default false and also there are APIs which are using rtl and i don't wan't to ignore them .